# Best way to do events with the PopUpManager?

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex3, adobe, cairngorm

If I am using the PopUpManager to add a child, and I dispatch an event from that child, the bubbles don't seem to bubble to the top of my application (main application).

For instance:

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp( popup, parentApplication as Application, false );
```

Then in the popup, I do:

```
dispatchEvent( new Event( "testEvent", true ) );
```

I have an eventListener in parentApplication (root .mxml) for "testEvent", but it never fires. Because of this, I have been dispatching events and listening for events on the ModelLocator (using cairngorm). This obviously is not ideal, because I have to manually make sure I remove the event listeners in a lot of cases.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: are you doing? popup.addEventListener( "testEvent", callbackFucntion );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more familiar with Mate than Cairngorm, but what I do in this situation is to back up my pop up with a model and dispatch the events off of the model. Since the model and the main application sit at the same level, the main application can hear the events.

**Update:**

Here's a rough example.

In my **MainMap.mxml** I create an instance of the presentation model and inject it into my popup.

```
<EventHandlers type="{ FlexEvent.PREINITIALIZE }">
  <ObjectBuilder generator="{ MyPopUpPresentationModel  }" constructorArguments="{ scope.dispatcher }"/>
</EventHandlers>

<Injectors target="{ MyPopUp }">
    <PropertyInjector targetKey="model" source="{ MyPopUpPresentationModel }"/>
</Injectors>
```

And In **MyPopUp.mxml** I have an instance of my model.

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    [Bindable] public var model:MyPopUpPresentationModel;
  ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Here's **MyPopUpPresentationModel.as**.

```
package
{
  private var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;
  public function DigitalTagTrackingPresentationModel(target:IEventDispatcher)
  {
    this.dispatcher = target;
  }

  public function dispatchMyCustomEvent():void
  {
    dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event("MyCustomEvent"));
  }
}
```

When you call `model.dispatchMyCustomEvent();` from **MyPopUp.mxml** it will dispatch the event using the scope of the presentation model's dispatcher which will be at the same level as the parent application. I hope this helps!

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? It sounds promising but I don't quite understand what you mean by "backing up your popup."

Comment: @andrewpthorp, I added a quick example on how I would do this using Mate. Like I said, I'm not too familiar with Cairngorm, so hopefully you can adapt it for your use. :)

Comment: I like this solution. It is a Flex 4 solution, but I believe I will be able to do something similar adapting it to Flex 3/Cairngorm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
var popup:SomePopup = PopUpManager.createPopup(this, SomePopup, true) as SomePopup;
popup.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, onClose);
```

And make sure you remove that even listener when the popup closes.

Comment: @J_A_X, Just out of curiosity, why would using `createPopUp` vs. `addPopUp` enable the parentApplication to hear the events dispatched by the pop up?

Comment: no, they pretty much do the same, I just like createPopup better. The parent cannot listen to any popups because they're displayed on a separate stage.  You can only listen to popups if you add the listeners directly to them.

Comment: I can hear events on the popup itself just fine. Only where the popup is created though. If I want a bubbling event, it won't bubble to the parent application.

Comment: No, it won't.  Why would you?  If you really need it to bubble to the top, I would add a listener to the popup itself which then dispatches another event that's actually within the display list.

Comment: That's the point of a bubbling event. I wan't it to bubble to the top, without creating and dispatching multiple events.

Comment: *sigh* you don't seem to understand.  Popups are NOT on the same display list, hence bubbling from within popup will *never* reach the root view (application).  You'll need to listen to the popup for the event, then dispatch from the component on the display list again.  There's no other way unless you call the root view directly through FlexGlobals.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch bubbling events at the top, you can add your event listener to FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.  Hope that helps.

Comment: systemManager.addEventListener is the absolute top of a flash application? PopUpManager sits under systemManager? This is useful information.

Answer (score 0):

In your popup, you can use:
Application.application.dispatchEvent, as long as you listener itself is attached to Application.application.

I'm actually not a big fan of dispatching on Application.application, because it reduces the reusability of the component model, but in a pinch it does work.